# How to show $(1^2)(3^2)(5^2)...((p-2)^2)=(-1)^{(p+1)/2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show the above problem using Wilson's theorem, which I know is $(p-1)!\equiv(-1)$ mod p. If I start with this I get $1\dot{}2\dot{}3\dot{}...\dot{}(p-1)\equiv(-1)$ mod p, but I don't know what I can do from here and how I'm going to get rid of the even numbers on the left, which is hopefully how I will get the exponent on the right, but I'm unsure. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: @ale you made a mistake in the edit, $!=$ was factorial and not $\ne$. Be a bit careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Wilson's Theorem, $$(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$$

Now as, $\displaystyle p-r\equiv -r\pmod p\iff r\equiv -(p-r)$

$\displaystyle(p-1)!$

$\displaystyle\equiv[1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(p-2)][-(p-2)\cdot -(p-4)\cdots \{-p-(p-3)\}\cdot\{-p-(p-1)\}]$
$\displaystyle\equiv [1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(p-2)]^2 (-1)^{\left(\dfrac{p-2-1}2+1\right)}$

$\displaystyle\implies [1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(p-2)]^2 (-1)^{\dfrac{p-1}2}\equiv-1\pmod p$

$\displaystyle\implies [1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(p-2)]^2\equiv-1\cdot (-1)^{\dfrac{p-1}2}\pmod p$

Comment: Can you tell me how you go from the line that say [-(p-2)*-(p-4)...{-p-(p-3)}*{-p-(p-1)}] to the (-1)^(((p-2-1)/2)+1) part? That's the only step I'm getting lost on.

Comment: I think I figured it out, is it because you are taking the (-1) out of all the terms in the second group. This gives you the same numbers as on the left so it becomes squared. Also the number of terms that you factored out a negative are (((p-2-1)/2)+1). Is that it or did I make a mistake?